# Refresh ASP.NET page using custom event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events

I have created a List which generates a custom event based on Example 1 from this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and I need to update an aspx page whenever there are any new elements in the List.

When I debug the application I can see that the value was updated, but nothing appears on the page.

**ASPX**

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
                <asp:Label ID="xpto" runat="server" Text="zzzzzzzzzzzz"></asp:Label>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
MessageHandling.DashboardRequests.Changed += new EventHandler(ListChanged);
...
...
...
private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    xpto.Text = dt.ToString();
}
```

***EDIT:***

If I change the UpdateMode to Always and ListChanged method to:

```
private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  xpto.Text = dt.ToString();
  UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.
```

And if I set the UpdateMode to Conditional nothing happens again.

If I create a timer and add this method:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  xpto.Text = dt.ToString();
}
```

the xpto is updated in the timer method correctly

Comment: Why are you using `UpdateMode="Conditional"`? and when are you updating the `UpdatePanel`? Check [UpdatePanel UpdateMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @AteşGÜRAL - Your link is wrong I think you meant this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx

Comment: Added information in the original post

Comment: balizeiro I think there is a misunderstanding here, if you set Update mode to Always you don't need to do `UpdatePanel1.Update()` I mean at least that is how I use it.So set it conditional and do `UpdatePanel1.Update()` when needed, or set it to always and do not use `UpdatePanel1.Update()`.

Comment: I tried both of those manners but nothing happens. The weird thing is if I try the update from a Timer event, everything works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Change `UpdateMode` to `Always` as suggested by Ates.

---

(old)

The code looks ok, so I will make a WAG -- are you updating `xpto.Text` *ANYWHERE* else in the page lifecycle?

Comment: No, the only place where xpto is referenced is in ListChanged(...)

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of your code, I will note the example you were looking at is not an ASP.NET example but a windows forms example